# Android ParseQuery empty results

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to make a parse query from my activity. It's working fine, i'm able to retrieve my objects but there are always empty (ie match.user1 always null)

```
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

ParseQuery<Match> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Match.class);
query.whereEqualTo("user1", user);
query.include("user1");
query.include("user2");

query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Match>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<Match> list, ParseException e) {
        if(e == null){
            // list[0].user1 = null
        }
    }
});
```

In my ApplicationController

```
ParseObject.registerSubclass(Match.class);
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
Parse.initialize(this, "XXX", "XXX");
```

What's wrong in my code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try get the references object (in your case columns 'user1' and 'user2') as following:

```
list.get(0).getParseObject('user1')
```

this give you the reference object then you can access it's values (columns) user the getters methods

Comment: I can't use the attribute of my ParseObject subclass ? I need to set for instance : match.user1 = list.get(0).getParseObject('user1') ?